# Is HP cumulative or individually?

Tags: clash-royale

Level 1 minion horde card shows hitpoints to be 90. Now is it the hitpoint of one minion or all of them together. If it is of one than total HP should be 6*90 =540.

Which one is it?

Comment: It's probably 90 hp per minion, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 5):

The stats displayed are per 1 unit. One of that stats is "Count" where applicable which shows how many units will be spawned with those stats shown.